# Material UI add and remove dynamically panels

Tags: javascript, reactjs

https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-shadow-eizt3?fontsize=14&file=/src/Panel.js

Please refer above example.

I want to add dynamically panels.Currently adding only one and after that if i press add, it is not adding.
Each panel must be a remove button by click that, user can remove that panel.

Please help in this, I  really appreciate your effort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should assign the `points` to your `arr` variable in `addPoint` function to append the panels. I added some stuff to make `expanded` and `onChange` working dynamically with the panel indexes. You can check out my changes [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-driscoll-skoq1?file=/src/Panel.js).

Comment: I got your points it is adding multiple panels. Thanks for it.

Comment: But second part of question is still pending. If a user want to remove perticular panel , how can we do that

Comment: Okay, let me add it for you.

Comment: @DhananjaySharma I just add remove functionality, you can the example again.

Comment: Thank you very much.You saved my day.I really appreciate your efforts. Thanks again for your valuable time.